# Has intermittent fasting without calorie reduction/increase any deleterious side effects, aside perhaps on sleep, cortisol, and gallstones?

Tags: fasting

Has intermittent fasting without calorie reduction/increase any deleterious side effects, aside perhaps on [sleep](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/20735/43), [cortisol](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/20731/43) and [gallstones](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/20760/43)?

I have read a fair amount of articles on intermittent fasting but aside from some perhaps negative side effects on sleep, cortisol and gallstones, all other deleterious sides effects I have read stem from  calorie reduction/increase.

Comment: Seems unlikely it would be harmful given that intermittent fasting would have been a part of daily life for humans for 100s of thousands of years.